# How filter by date and convert datetime

Tags: python, django, database, datetime, django-rest-framework

I am sending some dates from the front made in vue. I am receiving these dates in my viewSet in django, I want to filter data from these received dates.
I have two questions:

1. How do I convert dates into Python Datetime?
2. How do I filter the dates equal or greater or equal or less. => <=
   In other words: bring records whose date is equal to or greater than another date.

date format in the front: 2021-08-03 10:12:14

date format in the back:

```
    # print(type(fechas['desde']))
    fecha <class 'str'>
    # print(fechas['desde'])
    fecha 2021-08-03 10:12:14
```

VIEWSET:

```
            class TecnicosViewSet(
                    mixins.CreateModelMixin,
                    mixins.UpdateModelMixin,
                    mixins.RetrieveModelMixin,
                    mixins.ListModelMixin,
                    mixins.DestroyModelMixin,
                    viewsets.GenericViewSet):

                queryset = Tecnico.objects.all()
                serializer_class = Tecnicoserializer

                def list(self, request):
                    dataQ = request.GET
                    newQ = json.dumps(dict(dataQ))
                    newQ1= json.loads(newQ)
                    tecnicos = ''
                    fechas= json.loads(newQ1['fechas'][0])
                    for item in newQ1['tecnicos']:
                        itemN = json.loads(item)
                        tecnicos = itemN['tecnicos']
                    print('fechas', fechas['desde'], fechas['hasta'])
                    # fecha = datetime.strptime(fechas['desde'], '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M')
                    print('fecha', type(fechas['desde']))
                    print('fecha', fechas['desde'])
                    for id in tecnicos:
                        ordenes = Servicio_realizados_orden_trabajo.objects.filter(date_range = [fechas['desde'], fechas['hasta']]).filter(state = 1).filter(tecnico = id)
                        ordenS = ServicioRealizadosserializer(ordenes, many=True)


                    return Response({'OK'})
```

As I fixed before: I want to convert that date into understandable python format and then use that transformed date to filter data by that date.

The for loop seen in the viewsewt is where I am trying to do the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty close based off your code...

You basically use strptime to convert a string to date in a desired format and then once you have created python datetime objects you can compare them.

Here's an example:

```
from datetime import datetime

date = datetime.strptime("2021-08-03 10:12:14", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
if date >= datetime.strptime("2021", "%Y"):
    print('After or in 2021')
if date >= datetime.strptime("2021-09", "%Y-%m"):
    print('After or in September 2021')
```